# Story ID - aliens pit humans against other aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi, mars

Another book series where I can't remember the author of title. Published in the last 10 years. Earth has made contact with aliens who claim that their enemies have landed on mars and are coming for us. These enemy aliens use poison darts and other bio weapons. It turns out that the aliens are doing this as a sort of reality show, pitting humans against other aliens who are also duped. Thanks

Comment: Brevity is not valued in story-ID questions. On the contrary, you should tell us everything you can remember about the story, no matter how unimportant it may seem to you, and don't worry about spoilers.

Comment: Sounds a bit like "Invasion: Earth" by Harry Harrison.  But I don't think that was a series and it's earlier than your timeframe.   https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1977036.Invasion_Earth